# Select dropdown displays first option instead of selected one

Tags: html

I have observed very strange behavior of html's select. When the page starts loading selected option is displayed (Oprion 3). When the page is fully loaded select resets to its first option (Option 1). The source of the page shows selected attribure on the third option, below:

```
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <select>
      <option value="value 1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="value 2">Option 2</option>
      <option selected value="value 3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any ideas what may be the cause?

Comment: There's no javascript of any kind?

Comment: do you have any JS touching the form?

Comment: The code itself couldn't have caused such a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/4ckeY/

Comment: I have checked with you code, there is no such issue. Do you have other javscript in the code?

Comment: Thank you all. I have found JS code that was causing this:
  $(options).removeAttr('selected');
  $(options[map[my_array]]).attr('selected', 'selected');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found JS code that was causing this:

```
$(options).removeAttr('selected'); 
$(options[map[my_array]]).attr('selected', 'selected');
```